# MySQL Inner Join 'Unknown column'

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, inner-join

I did my reading on this and still can't make sense why my query doesn't work. It's a rather simple INNER JOIN and we're working on MySQL5. I know, there was a change with join with the precedence of explicitly called joins over comas. But I'm not doing any of that.

My assembled query looks like this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS k_services.id, service_status, service_tourno, service_date, service_cxlDate, service_difficultPeriod, service_priority, service_currency, service_key_so, service_price_so, service_key_ok, service_price_cfm, service_supplement 
    FROM  k_services
    JOIN k_remarks ON k_remarks.remark_service = k_services.id
    WHERE  k_services.service_market = 2 AND k_remarks.remark_type = 9
    LIMIT 0, 25
```

Which returns me an error:

> Unknown column 'k_remarks.remark_type' in 'where clause.

However, when I pop this exact same query into SQLyog it executes just fine with the desired/expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS k_services.id, service_status, service_tourno, service_date, service_cxlDate, service_difficultPeriod, service_priority, service_currency, service_key_so, service_price_so, service_key_ok, service_price_cfm, service_supplement 
    FROM  k_services
    JOIN k_remarks ON (k_remarks.remark_service = k_services.id AND k_remarks.remark_type = 9)
    WHERE  k_services.service_market = 2 
    LIMIT 0, 25
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks a lot.
What's the simple explanation for this?